# jrails_auto_complete setup help

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jrails, jrails-auto-complete

I have been struggling to get a simple autocomplete working with my Rails app using the jQuery UI 'autocomplete'  I'm already using jRails, so I tried using the [jrails_auto_complete](http://github.com/evilmarty/jrails_auto_completeID=auto_complete_for_user_nameBlockquote)

I set it up like it says in the README, but I get the following javascript error when I start typing in the box:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

URL: /users/auto_complete_for_user_name?term=a
```

And when I debug it it says:

**Couldn't find User with ID=auto_complete_for_user_name**

Any ideas? I would think it would take more than the two steps listed but I'm pretty sure I setup those two correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that you need to add the following to your routes.rb file:

```
map.resources :users, :collection => {:auto_complete_for_user_name => :get}
```